# Using Trollop for command line parsing in Ruby, how do I override the 'version' parameter

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, trollop

I have a Ruby program that needs to take a version as a parameter.  This version refers to the version of a resource the program will interact with, not the version of the program itself.  I found Trollop and have been pleased with it's simplicity.  However, it appears that Trollop automatically creates a --version flag to print out the version of the program.  I want my version flag to take a string as a parameter.

Google searches have turned up the following in History.txt of the Trollup project:

```
== 1.3 / 2007-01-31
* Wrap at (screen width - 1) instead of screen width.
* User can override --help and --version.
* Bugfix in handling of -v and -h.
* More tests to confirm the above.
```

So it appears, from the history, that I should be able to override --version.
However, when I create a --version option and pass it in, the program exits immediately.

```
opts = Trollop::options do
  opt : version, "The version to use.  ie. 1.0.1", :type => String, :required => true
end
```

The code above correctly requires the version parameter to be passed in.  However, when I pass it in, the program immediately exits.  I think it is printing version (which apparently is nil) and exiting.

How do I override version to take an argument in Trollop?

Comment: can you change your option's name to `:program_version` or something? I wonder if your input is conflicting with the Trollop version.

Comment: Changing to program_version does work, and I think you are right about conflicting with the Trollop version.  I just thought maybe there was a correct way of overriding it based on the history.txt that says "User can override --help and --version."

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what they mean.  That version is for displaying/overriding the Trollop program version(the script your user will run).  However, you want to take version as an input for some other version, correct?

Comment: That is correct.  The version I want to take as a parameter deals with the version of a resource the program will interact with, not the version of the program itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your option as anything other than `:version` then configure the `:long` and `:short` forms as `version` and `v`.

```
opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :use_version, "The version to use.  ie. 1.0.1", 
    :long => 'version', :short => 'v', :type => String, :required => false
end
```

When you define the option as `:version`, the default `:version` definition is overridden but Trollop still [throws a `VersionNeeded` exception](https://github.com/ManageIQ/trollop/blob/3a0a39157a71281922827f63ac947ad893aede63/lib/trollop.rb#L363) when it see's the `:version` option has been supplied. Trollop then prints the version and exits immediately.

The same idea applies to `:help` too.